# How to disable chrome details label default behavior

Tags: html, google-chrome

In Chrome

I wang to use details label `<details>details</details>`.

But I don't need his default behavior.

I how to disable it?

http://jsfiddle.net/x8csg/

Answer (score 0):

```
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8csg/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!  But when you click on the time still will trigger the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do i can suggest the following:

```
$('details').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

You have to prevent the default behavior. Like you want to block buttons submitting a form ...

Please mind that in this case the details are going to be hidden, so you have to change to:

```
<details open>details</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, a more complete answer — this must be adjusted on both CSS and Javascript:

**Javascript:**

```
var d=document.querySelectorAll('details:not(open)'), 
    i=d.length,
    f=function(e){e.preventDefault();};

while(i-- > 0) {

    // set the open attribute to the elements that doesn't have one 
    d[i].setAttribute('open',''); 

    // disable open/close behavior
    d[i].onclick = f;
}
// cleanup
delete(d);
delete(i);
delete(f);
```

Or jQuery style:

```
$('details:not(open)').attr('open',true).click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

**CSS:**

```
/* disable <summary> marker/arrow on webkit */
summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none;}

/* disable outline when clicked */
summary:focus{outline:none;}
```

Comment: Putting your code in a closure would be much cleaner than trying to delete globals.